# UI support by UIAutomationClient

Tags: c#, .net, automation, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am looking for some details about `UIAutomationClient`.

I want to know which type of `element\application` it supports like `WPF, Win 32, JAVA, Sliverlight`.

If anyone has a link where all the supported control complete list I can find then it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Presentation Foundation Controls, Win32, Windows Forms Controls

UI Automation provides full functionality in Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, and later operating systems.

Please refer the below three docs for more details :

[UI Automation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-uiautomationoverview)

[UI Automation Support for Standard Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-support-for-standard-controls)

[UI Automation Control Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-control-types)

I hope this helps.